# iOS push notification app not asking for permission on registration

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rubymotion

I am working on an app which requires push notifications to be enabled. I have followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) article and worked fine till I downloaded the provisioning profile. I am using Rubymotion to develop this app and hence in my Rakefile I Did this,

```
app.name = 'Myapp'
app.identifier = 'com.myapp.development'
app.provisioning_profile = '/Users/sunilkumar/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/Myapp_Development.mobileprovision'
```

'My App' is the name of my app. Identifier is the project identifier (as per the Rubymotion docs and as per my belief thats the bundle identifier ), the default value of which I override to make it same as the App Id which I created in the IOS development center.

In my app_delegate.rb, I also have this piece of code,

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)
```

The issue is that when the device is connected and the app installed, the permission for push notifications is not being asked. I guess I have done almost everything right and is as per the article I linked above, but somehow it just doesn't seem to work. Any help on this would be must appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sunil to just understand this fully. Have you never had the popup to accept push messages? Are push messages delivered to your device? BR Lasse

Comment: No Lasse, there was never a popup to accept push messages.

Comment: Is `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]` being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out guys.

I had to set the aps-environment in my RubyMotion project's Rakefile.

```
app.entitlements['aps-environment'] = 'development'  
app.entitlements['get-task-allow'] = true
```

As soon as I did, it worked for me. Thanks all for the responses.

Comment: This is the rakefile configuration for a Rubymotion project.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have installed this app before. iOS only ask permission for push once a day per application. So, you will need to change the system time ahead 2 days or more, reboot the device then change systime back. This will make permission alert be asked again.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling Push notification for you app you need to create SSL certificate then generate new provisional profile.

Hope it resolve your problem

Comment: I have already created the SSL certificate, 'aps_development.cer' and I have generated the new provisioning profile mentioned in the question.

Comment: there is something happening wrong when you are performing administrative for push notification. please make once again all the certificate and provisional profile

Comment: I have done that and still its the same. Doesn't Iphone give some kind of error sign when there is a problem with push notifications?